# Class member variables vs createRef to store mutable data in React class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For functional components it is encouraged to use `useRef` not just for access to dom elements but also to [store some data](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) that you do not want to trigger a rerender for.

For class components, I cannot find much information if using `createRef` to store data that you do not want to trigger a rerender for is a good idea or not. I understand that class member variables will work for primitive values but I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697268/member-variables-in-react-class-are-shared-by-reference) that it might not be a good idea for non primitive values. So if you're storing an object for whatever reason, maybe an object of axios's [cancellation tokens](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) for each type of request? (The example is just for illustrative purpose)

Can I have a rule of thumb to always use `createRef` to store any data, primitive and non-primitive that I don't want to store in my state?

I have not seen any documentation approving `createRef` to store mutable data in this way, is it because there's some pitfalls/performance issues or weird behaviour with hot reloading, etc that I might be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I have a rule of thumb to always use createRef to store any data, primitive and non-primitive that I don't want to store in my state?

In a class component, that's completely superfluous. A class component already has a mutable object: `this`. There's no need to create an additional one in the form of a ref.

Comment: I see, because it's not on the prototype, we explicitly set it in the constructor using `this.` Silly me, thanks!